# Why is sometime my Visual studio code not working evrytime?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax, traceback

```
car = 'subaru'
>>> & C:/Users/ANTHONY/anaconda3/python.exe "d:/python programs vsc/login.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 File "<stdin>", line 1
```

OR(check this program)

```
car = 'subaru'
print("Is car == 'subaru'? I predict True.")
print(car == 'subaru')
print("\nIs car == 'audi'? I predict False.")
print(car == 'audi')

>>> print(car == 'audi')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'car' is not defined
```

But this program works fine in python terminal or even in Juptyter notebook. I tried changing environments, sometimes it works fine.. other time it do not

Comment: Where are you running this? Visual Studio Code is an IDE (i.e. text editor), but both these programs seems to be running in an interactive terminal, not with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: yes these seems fine in interctive terminal as well as PycharmJupyter, etc .... It was working well before. Dont know whats the issue here

Comment: @Antony Joy -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for following up Jill, sorry for replying late....wasn't notified  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the content recognized by different terminals is different.

1. Since "Python Interactive Terminal" is used for code interaction, it recognizes python code. Therefore, when the run button is clicked, (it executes python commands,) but the "Python Interactive Terminal" cannot recognize commands. Therefore, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" is displayed.

   Solution: Please use the command "`exit()`" to exit this interactive window, or click the "Kill terminal" icon of the terminal, and then open a new terminal.

   [image]
2. As for "NameError: name'car' is not defined", we need to input the value of the variable "car" and then use the output statement to judge it:

   [image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer   :)           ...but I moved to pycharm and Visual studio and stopped using VSC... but i tried the second  code right now and it works perfectly well....   and for the first one nope...its still not working          car = 'subaru'
>>> & C:/Users/ANTHONY/anaconda3/python.exe "d:/python programs vsc/login.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1

Comment: @ Antony Joy -If the command "exit()" does not work, you could try to delete the VS Code terminal you are using ("Kill terminal" icon), and then use Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal.

Comment: Thanks Cheng... seems to work fine now :)